# PostgreSQL: Composite Primary Keys: no unique constraint matching given keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why does the following return `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "cats"` ?

```
CREATE TABLE cats (
  name varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  owner_id varchar(36) NOT NULL REFERENCES owners (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

  PRIMARY KEY (name, owner_id)
);
```

I could do ...

```
CREATE TABLE cats (
  name varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  owner_id varchar(36) NOT NULL REFERENCES owners (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

  PRIMARY KEY (name, owner_id),
  UNIQUE (name),
  UNIQUE (owner_id)
);
```

which doesn't return any error. But this means that cat names can't be given twice (or more) by different cat owners?

Basically, this is what I want:

```
cats.name | cats.owner  
DAISY     | BOB
NALA      | BOB
NALA      | CARL
```

Comment: Don't put a unique constraint on `name` since it is not meant to be unique.

Comment: that didn't fix it unfortunately. same error.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the create, I get the following error:

> Schema Creation Failed: ERROR: column "id" named in key does not exist:

You need to define the columns used in the primary key.

Using `name` does seem to fix the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE cats (
  name varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  owner_id varchar(36) NOT NULL REFERENCES owners (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

  PRIMARY KEY (name, owner_id)
);
```

Comment: Yep, I was playing with this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8e8c - it builds fine.

Comment: sorry! ``PRIMARY KEY (id, owner_id)`` was meant to be ``PRIMARY KEY (name, owner_id)``.